# How to use specific interface and not general interface in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, interface, casting

**Introduction**

Let's say I have a class AssemblyLine. An AssemblyLine contains multiple steps. Each Step can be executed:

```
public interface IStep
{
    IContext Execute(IContext context);
}
```

Each Step gets a specific IContext, which has some information about what to process.

The AssemblyLine contains multiple Steps. They can be executed by calling Execute on the AssemblyLine:

```
public class Assemblyline
{
    private readonly List<IStep> _steps;

    public Assemblyline(List<IStep> steps)
    {
        _steps = steps;
    }

    public void Execute(IContext context)
    {
        foreach (var step in _steps)
        {
            step.Execute(context);
        }
    }
}
```

I have a general IContaxt interface:

```
public interface IContext
{
    string Id { get; set; }
}
```

And specific Contexts:

```
public interface IAbcContext : IContext
{
    string Abc { get; set; }
}

public interface IDefContext : IContext
{
    string Def { get; set; }
}

public class XyzContext : IAbcContext, IDefContext
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Abc { get; set; }

    public string Def { get; set; }
}
```

The Contexts can be handled by specific Steps:

```
public class AbcStep : IStep
{
    public IContext Execute(IContext context)
    {
        var abcContext = (IAbcContext) context;
        abcContext.Abc = "some value for Abc";
        return abcContext;
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
}


public class DefStep : IStep
{
    public IContext Execute(IContext context)
    {
        var defContext = (IDefContext)context;
        defContext.Def = "some value for Def";
        return defContext;

    }

    public string Id
    {
        get; set; }
}
```

This is how I can execute the code:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        var steps = new List<IStep>();
        steps.Add(new AbcStep());
        steps.Add(new DefStep());

        var assemblyline = new Assemblyline(steps);

        var context = new XyzContext {Id = "1", Abc = "blabla", Def = "other value"};
        assemblyline.Execute(context);
    }
}
```

**Question**

In each specific Step I have to cas the IContext to the class that I really want. See this line:

**var abcContext = (IAbcContext) context;**

```
public class AbcStep : IStep
{
    public IContext Execute(IContext context)
    {
        var abcContext = (IAbcContext) context;
        abcContext.Abc = "some value for Abc";
        return abcContext;
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

I was hoping I could leave the cast, and do it like this:

```
public class AbcStep : IStep
{
    public IContext Execute(IAbcContext context)
    {
        context.Abc = "some value for Abc";
        return context;
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

But then I get this message:

Interface member 'Execute(IContext)' is not implemented.

Is there anyway I can remove the cast? Maybe use generics or something?

Comment: Your problem is not that cast alone (which will fail in a lot of cases). This whole thing seems not clearly concepted.

Comment: Something, somewhere, is going to have to do this cast or another. E.g. if you made `IStep` generic in its context, you'd a) have to introduce a new non-generic base for `IStep` to implement, so that you can still store all of them (despite their different generic types) in a single `List<T>` and b) have to cast them to their appropriate type before you can invoke the `Execute` method.

Comment: I don't quite understand after looking through a couple of times, but one obvious point is the reason you're having to cast is because the method you're trying to use is not part of your IContext interface. And you seem to have different methods in your different implementations. Why can you not standardise your interface?

Comment: Adding a specific implementation of an interface method would be to resolve a naming collision. You do not have one.

Comment: You could implement a `SetValue` for the IContext - perhaps that would help. The context itself then has to know how to handle that.

Comment: I've been having similar problems concerning parallel inheritance hierarchies (in your case the contexts and the steps) from time to time. Generics can help a little. However, I figured out that it's best to avoid such designs at all. Mostly they are somehow flawed anyway. For example, what should happen if you pass a context which does not implement `IDefContext` to an assemly line which contains `DefStep`s? Does it make sense? Probably not. So why trying to convince the type checker that it does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible with generics and some inheritance (comments in the code):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test
{
    public interface IStep
    {
        IContext Execute(IContext context);
    }

    // Make a generic version also
    public interface IStep<T> : IStep where T : IContext
    {
        T Execute(T context);
    }

    public class Assemblyline
    {
        private readonly List<IStep> _steps;

        public Assemblyline(List<IStep> steps)
        {
            _steps = steps;
        }

        public void Execute(IContext context)
        {
            foreach (var step in _steps)
            {
                step.Execute(context);
            }
        }
    }

    public interface IContext
    {
        string Id { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IAbcContext : IContext
    {
        string Abc { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IDefContext : IContext
    {
        string Def { get; set; }
    }

    public class XyzContext : IAbcContext, IDefContext
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string Abc { get; set; }

        public string Def { get; set; }
    }

    // This will do the casting for you
    public abstract class BaseStep<T> : IStep<T> where T : IContext
    {
        public abstract T Execute(T context);

        public IContext Execute(IContext context)
        {
            return (IContext)Execute((T)context);
        }

    }

    // Now less code for you:
    public class AbcStep : BaseStep<IAbcContext>
    {
        public override IAbcContext Execute(IAbcContext context)
        {
            var abcContext = context;
            abcContext.Abc = "some value for Abc";
            return abcContext;
        }

        public string Id { get; set; }
    }


    public class DefStep : BaseStep<IDefContext>
    {
        public override IDefContext Execute(IDefContext context)
        {
            var defContext = context;
            defContext.Def = "some value for Def";
            return defContext;

        }

        public string Id
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var steps = new List<IStep>();
            steps.Add(new AbcStep());
            steps.Add(new DefStep());

            var assemblyline = new Assemblyline(steps);

            var context = new XyzContext { Id = "1", Abc = "blabla", Def = "other value" };
            assemblyline.Execute(context);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: By the way, this will go bad if you pass it a context that does not implement the required interfaces for the steps. You could skip steps that do not have the required interface in the base class:

    if(context is T) {return (IContext)Execute((T)context);}
    else {return;}

Answer (score 0):

That is not necessarily your problem, but it was mine and your symptoms looks the same.

Do not try to create own dynamic typing system inside static-typed language.

Casting is bad, because it will fail while executing, not while compiling.

Each module must depend on interface it actually need for it's job and not depend on anything else. Using your example:

```
interface IXyzStepWork
{
    void DoXyz();
}

interface IAbcStepWork
{
    void DoAbc();
}

interface IAbcXyzWork : IAbcStepWork, IXyzStepWork
{
}

class AbcStep
{
    private readonly IAbcStepWork work;

    public AbcStep(IAbcStepWork work)
    {
        this.work = work;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        work.DoAbc();
    }
}

class AbcXyzStep
{
    private readonly IAbcXyzWork work;

    public AbcXyzStep(IAbcXyzWork work)
    {
        this.work = work;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        work.DoAbc();
        work.DoXyz();
    }
}
```

Next you can write `IAssemblyLineItem`, implement it by "step-classes"  and create `AssemblyLine` which will use it.

Yes, it's simple, obvious, not using generics. As for me, that is the right way for future development.

**UPD**: How to create single assembly line in your example.

```
interface IAssemblyLineItem
{
    void Execute();
}

class AssemblyLineService
{
    public void ExecuteAll(IEnumerable<IAssemblyLineItem> items)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            item.Execute();
        }
    }
}
```

Implement `IAssemblyLineItem` by "step-classes" and it will work.

And usage:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AbcXyzWork work = new AbcXyzWork();

        AbcStep abcStep = new AbcStep(work);

        AbcXyzStep abcxyzStep = new AbcXyzStep(work);

        AssemblyLineService line = new AssemblyLineService();

        line.ExecuteAll(new IAssemblyLineItem[] { abcStep, abcxyzStep });

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Notice: `Program.Main` depends on each class of the system - as it does in your initial example.

Comment: I was thinking about that too. This leads to a little more code. I have to create specific AssemblyLines and not one general.